Move stroke gradient definition from SVG to CSS
There is a gradient, defined like this:
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="out-of-flow">
    <defs>
        <!-- Gradients for circle charts. -->
        <linearGradient id="circle-graph-blue-greenish-gradient">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#00d5bd" />
            <stop offset="100" stop-color="#24c1ed" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>

It is referenced in a CSS class, applied to a <path> in another <svg>:


.circle-graph-blue-greenish {
  stroke: url(#circle-graph-blue-greenish-gradient);
  stroke-width: 5;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

svg {
  height: 50vh;
}
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="out-of-flow">
    <defs>
        <!-- Gradients for circle charts. -->
        <linearGradient id="circle-graph-blue-greenish-gradient">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#00d5bd" />
            <stop offset="100" stop-color="#24c1ed" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="rotate-90" width="75%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path class="circle-graph-underlay" d="M5,50 A45,45,0 1 1 95,50 A45,45,0 1 1 5,50"></path>
    <path d="M5,50 A45,45,0 1 1 95,50 A45,45,0 1 1 5,50" class="circle-graph circle-graph-blue-greenish"
        style="stroke-dashoffset: 251.677;stroke-dasharray: 282.783;"></path>
</svg>



It perfectly works. I want to move the gradient definition into the CSS class:
.circle-graph-blue-greenish
{
    stroke: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,213,189,1) 0%, rgba(36,193,237,1) 100%);
    stroke-width: 5;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}

But unfortunately it has stopped working (no visible stroke).
Why aren't both definitions equivalent and how do I define the gradient for stroke in CSS?
UPD It seems I can move the color values:
<stop offset="0" stop-color="var(--circle-graph-blue-greenish-gradient-color-1)" />

Better than nothing.
UPD 2 Unfortunately, the answer from here is not satisfactory for me.
It seems it is impossible to use variables like this:
.circle-graph-blue-greenish
{
    /*stroke: url(#circle-graph-blue-greenish-gradient);*/
    --color1: blue;
    --color2: red;
    stroke: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3ClinearGradient id='gradient'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='var(--color1)' /%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='var(--color2)' /%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3C/svg%3E#gradient");
    stroke-width: 5;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}

Using a duplicate value violates DRY and (especially, inside a quoted string) could be easy to overlook.

Essentially you can't. stroke requires a color in css and a gradient is not a color. Why can't you use the url?

Hello @Paulie_D. I'd like to keep gradient definitions apart from what they are applied to, just as for regular HTML elements.

As I said, you can't. But you can still have the defs in a separate SVG

CSS gradients apply to HTML, SVG gradients are for SVG. You can't swap.

Tempting to do the whole thing in CSS. You don’t get the rounded line caps, but the code is so much neater.


.pie {
  --my-grey: #333333f4;
  --my-cyan: #00d5bd;
  --my-blue: #0072d5;
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;

  background-image:
    /* top layer masks the centre - can change this to solid black */
    radial-gradient(circle, var(--my-grey) 60%, transparent 60%),
    /* centre layer is the colourful edge */
    conic-gradient(transparent 75%, var(--my-blue) 75%, var(--my-cyan) 90%, transparent 90%),
    /* bottom layer is the black foundation */
    radial-gradient(circle, black 65%, transparent 65%);
}
<div class="pie"></div>



